# Multiple Lightbox (Modal Image Gallery) on 1 page

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, slideshow, lightbox

I would like to create a lightbox effect without downloading anything. I found a nice solution using Modal/Slideshow as a lightbox and it works well. I would like to have more than 1 on a page and can't get it to work. Here is a link to the example and all the code is below.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}
</style>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_fjords.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want more than 1 gallery on a page. So people can click one row of images and view the slideshow then click the next row and see a separate slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

Try if u are using bootstrap

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x200/" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x200/" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x200/" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x200/" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">×</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
        <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2500x500/" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
        <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2500x500/" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
        <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2500x500/" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
        <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/2500x500/" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="https://fakeimg.pl/250x250/" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="https://fakeimg.pl/250x250/" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="https://fakeimg.pl/250x250/" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="https://fakeimg.pl/250x250/" onclick="currentSlide(4)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

img.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}
```

JS

```
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer because I am working on the same concept (multiple lightboxes on one page) and used the same example code! It's partial because mine still has a couple issues, (the captions for the second lightbox aren't coming through yet and the "active" image stays opaque in the demo area for the second lightbox also.)
Hopefully someone can improve on what I've done!

What I found was that I needed to copy the JS and rename the functions for the second lightbox, then make sure you call the copied & renamed version for the second lightbox:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script>
   .demo, .demo2 {
   opacity: 0.6;
   margin-top: 1px;
 }

 .mySlides, .mySlides2 {
   display: none;
 }

 </script>
 <body>

 <h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

 <!-- First lightbox -->
 <div class="row">
   <div class="column">
     <img src="img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="img_fjords.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
     <img src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
   </div>
 </div>

 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
   <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
   <div class="modal-content">

     <div class="mySlides">
       <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
       <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <div class="mySlides">
       <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
       <img src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <div class="mySlides">
       <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
       <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <div class="mySlides">
       <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
       <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
     <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

     <div class="caption-container">
       <p id="caption"></p>
     </div>


     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo cursor" src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
     </div>
     <div class="column">
       <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
          </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Second lightbox -->
  <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
    <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal2()">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="mySlides2">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
        <img src="img/farm1Slice.png" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
        <img src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
        <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
        <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides2(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides2(1)">&#10095;</a>

      <div class="caption-container">
        <p id="caption"></p>
      </div>


      <div class="column">
        <img class="demo2 cursor" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide2(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img class="demo2 cursor" src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide2(2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img class="demo2 cursor" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide2(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img class="demo2 cursor" src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide2(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
           </div>
    </div>
  </div>


 <script>
 function openModal() {
   document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
 }

 function closeModal() {
   document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
 }

 var slideIndex = 1;
 showSlides(slideIndex);

 function plusSlides(n) {
   showSlides(slideIndex += n);
 }

 function currentSlide(n) {
   showSlides(slideIndex = n);
 }

 function showSlides(n) {
   var i;
   var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
   var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
   var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
   if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
   if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
   for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
   }
   for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
       dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
   }
   slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
   dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
   captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
 }
 </script>

 <!--Second lightbox code -->
 <script>
 function openModal2() {
   document.getElementById('myModal2').style.display = "block";
 }

 function closeModal() {
   document.getElementById('myModal2').style.display = "none";
 }

 var slideIndex = 1;
 showSlides2(slideIndex);

 function plusSlides2(n) {
   showSlides2(slideIndex += n);
 }

 function currentSlide2(n) {
   showSlides2(slideIndex = n);
 }

 function showSlides2(n) {
   var i;
   var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
   var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
   var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
   if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
   if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
   for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
   }
   for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
       dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
   }
   slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
   dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
   captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: hi, did you came up with a solution to this issue ?? having the same problem now thanks.

Comment: Sorry its been so long! I can't actually remember if I ended up using this code in the final project! Sorry I couldn't help more.